# Reference Request for the following

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

I'm preparing for interviews for quant based jobs and their tests include questions and puzzles from mostly combinatorics, linear algebra and most importantly probability (more focus on expectations).

Can someone suggest some links/books for the required. Any further suggestions on how to prepare well for these tests would be great too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

Mark Joshi, Nick Denson, Andrew Downes-Quant Job Interview Questions And Answers

I used this for my interviews.